# NewsFeed Posts are not showing

Tags: 2013, newsfeed

Newsfeed Posts were working before but when I post anything and click on "Following" link my post disappears.

My posts are visible in Activity tab but they are not visible on Following tab.

I tried to stop/start/remove/add Distributed cache but the problem persists.